# Django: Show the content of the model as per the current user logged in

Tags: django, django-models

I want to show the form content of the current user logged in
How can I achieve that

models.py

```
class Sign(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
regid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
phone = models.IntegerField()
car_type = models.ForeignKey(Cars, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pick_up = models.CharField(max_length=50)
destination = models.CharField(max_length=50)
guestname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hiuser')

class Meta:
    db_table = "Sign"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('final')
```

forms.py

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Sign
    fields = ['name', 'designation', 'email', 'pick_up', 'regid', 'car_type', 'guestname', 'destination', 'phone', ]

    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your Name'}),
        'designation': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control' }),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
        'pick_up': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Pick Up Location'}),
        'regid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Registration ID'}),
        'car_type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'guestname': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Guest Name(If Any)'}),
        'destination': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Destination'}),
        'phone': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone Number'}),

    }
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def booking(request):
    '''model = Sign
    form = BookingForm'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your Booking is Accepted')
            return redirect('final')
    else:
        form = BookingForm()
    return render(request, 'datas/booking.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my view for creating the form,now I want to show this content here:

```
@login_required
def final(request):
    bookings = Sign.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username=request.user))
    return render(request, 'datas/final.html', {'bookings': bookings})
```

final.html

```
{% extends 'datas/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <center><h1 style="color: steelblue">Your Booking</h1></center>
    <br><br>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Registration ID</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Pick Up Location</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% if bookings %}
{% for booking in bookings %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ booking.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ booking.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ booking.regid }}</td>
        <td>{{ booking.designation }}</td>
        <td>{{ booking.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{ booking.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ booking.pick_up }}</td>
        <td>{{ booking.destination }}</td>

        <td>

            <a href="{% url 'update' booking.pk %}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete' booking.pk %}" class="btn btn-success">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

How to display the booking content of the current user that is logged in? Should I use generic views? Also is there any clean and distinctive ways to display the content of final.html rather than using a table?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch data that are related to logged in users then you could use related_name to fetch data related to that user.

Since you have specified related_name to "User" in "Sign" as 'hiuser'.

`request.user.hiuser.all()` should give all the related "Sign" object of the user. In case if you haven't specified related name then you could use `request.user.sign_set.all()`

the default related_name pattern is `modelname_set`

So your view becomes:

```
    #bookings = Sign.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username=request.user)) # instead of this
    bookines = request.user.hiuser.all()
    return render(request, 'datas/final.html', {'bookings': bookings})
```

Comment: Both your and @Willem's codes helped me. So thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

The `request.user` attribute *is* a `User` object, so there is no need to fetch the object:

```
@login_required
def final(request):
    bookings = Sign.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'datas/final.html', {'bookings': bookings})
```

In the view where you add items, you should link the `request.user` to that object:

```
@login_required
def booking(request):
    '''model = Sign
    form = BookingForm'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your Booking is Accepted')
            return redirect('final')
    else:
        form = BookingForm()
    return render(request, 'datas/booking.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: I have changed the foreign key in model Sign  to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and changed the code as per your suggestion, but now the table is showing nothing.

Comment: @RinkumoniKhanikar: in your intial table the objects were likely not linked to the user. Please inspect the database. That is why `form.instance.user = request.user` links the new object to the logged in user.

Comment: I really liked your explanation and your code helped me.